# R Cannot Open Connection`

Tags: r, rjson

I am scraping from the NBA.com API for some shots data. The url that I am using is

```
url = "stats.nba.com/stats/shotchartdetail?CFID=33&CFPARAMS=2017-18&ContextFilter=&ContextMeasure=FGA&DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameID=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerID=101107&PlusMinus=N&PlayerPosition=&Rank=N&RookieYear=&Season=2017-18&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision="
```

This website can be easily verified to exist by copying and pasting into your browser. However, when I enter the line

```
data = rjson::fromJSON(file = url)
```

I get the error: Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection ... HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'.

I have tried adding http and https to the url but to no avail. Why is R not reading this url that clearly exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Overview

You need to download the data into [r](/questions/tagged/r) and then import that .json file inside of `fromJSON()`. I've shown how to go about extracting the two data frames contained in the list object `marvin.williams.shot.data`:

1. [Marvin William](http://stats.nba.com/player/101107/)'s individual 2017-2018 shot data; and
2. NBA league average shot data from the 2017-2018 season.

## Reproducible Example

```
# load necessary packages
library( jsonlite )

# load necessary data
download.file( url = "http://stats.nba.com/stats/shotchartdetail?CFID=33&CFPARAMS=2017-18&ContextFilter=&ContextMeasure=FGA&DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameID=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerID=101107&PlusMinus=N&PlayerPosition=&Rank=N&RookieYear=&Season=2017-18&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision="
               , destfile = "stats_nba.json" )

# transfrom into data frame
marvin.williams.shot.data <- 
  fromJSON( txt = "stats_nba.json" )

# view results
lapply( X = marvin.williams.shot.data, FUN = class)
# $resource
# [1] "character"
# 
# $parameters
# [1] "list"
# 
# $resultSets
# [1] "data.frame"

# transfrom the matrix into a data frame
player.shotchart.df <-
  as.data.frame( marvin.williams.shot.data$resultSets$rowSet[[1]]
                 , stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

# assign colnames
colnames( player.shotchart.df ) <-
  marvin.williams.shot.data$resultSets$headers[[1]]

# view results
dim( player.shotchart.df ) # [1] 563  24

# transfrom the matrix into a data frame
league.average.df <-
  as.data.frame( marvin.williams.shot.data$resultSets$rowSet[[2]]
                 , stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

# assign colnames
colnames( league.average.df ) <-
  marvin.williams.shot.data$resultSets$headers[[2]]

# view results
dim( league.average.df ) # [1] 20  7

# end of script #
```